# Alterar posição dos cursores do Lightbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou utilizando um plugin para fazer o efeito de lightbox(Segue o link abaixo desse texto), e preciso fazer algumas mudanças no visual, como o visual dos cursores e seus posicionamentos. Eu mudei o `close` dele para o topo e mudei as cores das setas, agora
estou tentando deixá-los para fora da imagem.

[LightBox: The original lightbox script](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

Consegui fazer isso com o cursor `next`, mas não com o `prev.` Eu tirei o `float:left` dos 2 cursores e no `next` eu coloquei uma `margin-left` e deu certo, já pro `prev`(cursor pra voltar)a margem não resolve nada, ela permanece no mesmo lugar.

[Imagem de como estou vendo](https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/464x639q90/540/hG332g.jpg)

### HTML

```
<div id='lightboxOverlay' class='lightboxOverlay'>
</div>

<div id='lightbox' class='lightbox'>
    <div class='lb-dataContainer'>
        <div class='lb-data'>
            <div class='lb-closeContainer'>
                <a class='lb-close'></a>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='lb-outerContainer'>
    <div class='lb-container'>
        <img class='lb-image' src='' />
            <div class='lb-nav'>
                <a class='lb-prev' href='' ></a>
                <a class='lb-next' href='' ></a>
            </div>
            <div class='lb-loader'>
                <a class='lb-cancel'></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='lb-dataContainer'>
        <div class='lb-data'>
            <div class='lb-details'>
                <span class='lb-caption'></span>
                <span class='lb-number'></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

### CSS

```
.lb-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.lb-container > .nav {
  left: 0;
}

.lb-nav a {
  outline: none;
  background-image: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==');
}

.lb-prev, .lb-next {
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-prev {
  width: 34%;
  left: 0;
  /*float: left;*/
  background: url(../images/prev.png) left 48% no-repeat;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
  margin-right: 10px !important;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-next {
  width: 64%;
  right: 0;
  /*float: right;*/
  background: url(../images/next.png) right 48% no-repeat;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
  margin-left: 44% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Resolução

**Finalmente eu consegui a resposta** !. Eu tirei a parte de `margin` que tinha feito e mudei a parte de `right` e `left`.

## Código

Colocarei aqui só o que eu adicionei.

```
.lb-prev, .lb-next {
    width: 50%;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.lb-prev{
    left:-60px;
}

.lb-next {
    right:-60px;
}
```

Comment: Esta é a solução para o problema? Se sim, edite sua resposta e deixe isso claro para quem pesquisar por isso futuramente. Se não, edite sua própria pergunta para adicionar informações.

Comment: Resposta alterada. Obrigado pelo "toque" @Andrey.

Comment: Allan, considere marcar sua resposta como correta, clicando à esquerda, abaixo da pontuação.